# How to report errors in a procedural macro using the quote macro?

Tags: error-handling, rust, rust-macros, rust-proc-macros

I am writing a procedural macro which works fine, but I am having trouble reporting errors in an ergonomic way. Using `panic!` "works" but is not elegant and does not present the error message to the user nicely.

I know that I can report good errors while parsing a `TokenStream`, but I need to produce errors while traversing the AST after it has been parsed.

The macro invocation looks like this:

```
attr_test! {
    #[bool]
    FOO
}
```

And should output:

```
const FOO: bool = false;
```

This is the macro code:

```
extern crate proc_macro;
use quote::quote;
use syn::parse::{Parse, ParseStream, Result};
use syn::{Attribute, parse_macro_input, Ident, Meta};

struct AttrTest {
    attributes: Vec<Attribute>,
    name: Ident,
}

impl Parse for AttrTest {
    fn parse(input: ParseStream) -> Result<Self> {
        Ok(AttrTest {
            attributes: input.call(Attribute::parse_outer)?,
            name: input.parse()?,
        })
    }
}

#[proc_macro]
pub fn attr_test(tokens: proc_macro::TokenStream) -> proc_macro::TokenStream {
    let test: AttrTest = parse_macro_input!(tokens);
    let name = test.name;
    let first_att = test.attributes
        .get(0)
        .and_then(|att| att.parse_meta().ok());
    if let Some(Meta::Word(ty)) = first_att {
        if ty.to_string() != "bool" {
            panic!("expected bool");
        }
        let output = quote! {
            const #name: #ty = false;
        };
        output.into()
    } else {
        panic!("malformed or missing metadata")
    }
}
```

I would like to produce an error if anything other than `bool` is specified in the attribute. For example, input like this:

```
attr_test! {
    #[something_else]
    FOO
}
```

should result in something like:

```
error: expected bool
attr_test! {
    #[something_else]
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected bool
    FOO
}
```

During parsing, there is a `Result`, which has lots of useful information including a `span`, so the resulting errors can highlight the exact parts of the macro call that have a problem. But once I'm traversing the AST, I can't see a good way to report errors.

How should this be done?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Apart from panicking, there are currently two ways to reports errors from a proc-macro: **[the unstable `Diagnostic` API](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/proc_macro/struct.Diagnostic.html) and "the `compile_error!` trick"**. Currently, the latter is mostly used because it works on stable. Let's see how they both work.

#### The `compile_error!` trick

Since Rust 1.20, [the `compile_error!` macro exists in the standard library](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/macro.compile_error.html). It takes a string and leads to an error at compile time.

```
compile_error!("oopsie woopsie");
```

Which leads to ([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5279fff5d75bab034dfe6eb3baee7f06)):

```
error: oopsie woopsie
 --> src/lib.rs:1:1
  |
1 | compile_error!("oopsie woopsie");
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This macro has been added for two cases: `macro_rules!` macros and `#[cfg]`. In both cases, library authors can add better errors if the user uses the macro incorrectly or has the wrong `cfg` values.

But proc-macro programmers had an interesting idea. As you might know, the `TokenStream` you return from your procedural macro can be created however you like. That includes the spans of those tokens: you can attach any spans you like to your output tokens. So the main idea is this:

**Emit a tokenstream containing `compile_error!("your error message");` but set the span of those tokens to the span of the input token that caused the error.** There is even a macro in `quote` which makes this easier: [`quote_spanned!`](https://docs.rs/quote/1.0.9/quote/macro.quote_spanned.html). In your case, we can write this:

```
let output = if ty.to_string() != "bool" {
    quote_spanned! {
        ty.span() =>
        compile_error!("expected bool");
    }
} else {
    quote! {
        const #name: #ty = false;
    }
};
```

For your faulty input, the compiler now prints this:

```
error: expected bool
 --> examples/main.rs:4:7
  |
4 |     #[something_else]
  |       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Why exactly does this work? Well: the error for `compile_error!` shows the code snippet containing the `compile_error!` invocation. For that, the span of the `compile_error!` invocation is used. But since we set the span to point to the faulty input token `ty`, the compiler shows the snippet underlining that token.

This trick is also used by `syn` to print nice errors. In fact, if you are using `syn` anyway, you can use its `Error` type and in particular the [`Error::to_compile_error` method](https://docs.rs/syn/1.0.70/syn/struct.Error.html#method.to_compile_error) which returns exactly the token stream we manually created with `quote_spanned!`:

```
syn::Error::new(ty.span(), "expected bool").to_compile_error()
```

---

#### The `Diagnostic` API

As this is still unstable, just a short example. The diagnostic API is more powerful than the trick above as you can have multiple spans, warnings and notes.

```
Diagnostic::spanned(ty.span().unwrap(), Level::Error, "expected bool").emit();
```

After that line, the error is printed, but you can still do stuff in your proc-macro. Usually, you would just return an empty token stream.

Comment: I'd like to point out that the `unwrap()` in `ty.span().unwrap()` is not anything with `Result`/`Option`, but a method for converting `proc_macro2::Span` to `proc_macro::Span`.

Comment: Noting here that the compile_error! trick is still handy when using syn, when the appropriate location is not in the derive input, but the derive declaration itself.

such as:


```
#[derive(YourMacro)]
               ^^^^^^^^^
                   your message
```.

It has workaround vibes but it's neat enough. Let me know if something cleaner is available.

Comment: Unfortunately `proc_macro::Diagnostic` is still unstable, and `ty.span().unwrap().error("...").emit()` (which is the same) is unstable too.

Answer (score 8):

The accepted answer mentioned the unstable `Diagnostic` API, which gives you much more power and control than the regular `compile_error`. Until the `Diagnostic` API stabilizes, [which probably will not be any time soon](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/54140), you can use the [`proc_macro_error`](https://docs.rs/proc-macro-error) crate. It provides a [`Diagnostic`](https://docs.rs/proc-macro-error/1.0.4/proc_macro_error/struct.Diagnostic.html) type that is designed to be API compatible with the unstable `proc_macro::Diagnostic`. The entire API is not implemented, only the part that can be reasonably implemented on stable. You can use it by simply adding the provided annotation to your macro:

```rust
#[proc_macro_error]
#[proc_macro]
fn my_macro(input: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    // ...
    Diagnostic::spanned(ty.span().unwrap(), Level::Error, "expected bool").emit();
}
```

`proc_macro_error` also provides some useful macros for emitting errors:

```rust
abort! { input,
    "I don't like this part!";
        note = "A notice message...";
        help = "A help message...";
}
```

However, you might want to consider sticking to using the `Diagnostic` type as it will make it easier to migrate to the the official `Diagnostic` API when it stabilizes.

Answer (score 2):

The existing solutions just rely on external libraries without explaining how it actually works.

You do not need to use `quote` or `proc-macro2`. Those are *convenience* libraries that make life a bit easier.

To render a `compiler_error` block, just literally do exactly that, like *this*:

```
use proc_macro::{Delimiter, Group, Ident, Literal, Punct, Spacing, Span, TokenStream, TokenTree};

enum MyErr {
    Nah,
}

fn my_macro_impl(input: TokenStream) -> Result<TokenStream, MyErr> {
    let tokens: Vec<TokenTree> = input.into_iter().collect();
    if tokens.len() != 0 {
        return Err(MyErr::Nah);
    }
    Ok([TokenTree::Literal(Literal::string("Hello world"))].into_iter().collect())
}

#[proc_macro]
pub fn my_macro(input: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    match my_macro_impl(input) {
        Ok(v) => v,
        Err(_) => [
            TokenTree::Ident(Ident::new("compile_error", Span::mixed_site())),
            TokenTree::Punct(Punct::new('!', Spacing::Alone)),
            TokenTree::Group(Group::new(
                Delimiter::Parenthesis,
                [TokenTree::Literal(Literal::string("Some error message here!"))].into_iter().collect(),
            )),
        ]
        .into_iter()
        .collect(),
    }
}
```

...and if you call it, like this:

```
use my_macros::my_macro;

#[test]
pub fn main() {
    assert_eq!(my_macro!("."), "Hello world");
}
```

You'll get this when you compile it:

```
error: Some error message here!
 --> tests/000_simple.rs:5:16
  |
5 |     assert_eq!(my_macro!("."), "Hello world");
  |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = note: this error originates in the macro `my_macro` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
```

`TokenStream` is a `Vec` of `TokenTree`; if you want to render the block:

> 'compiler_error' '!' '(' 'error' ')'

Then the AST you need to return is:

```
- Ident -> 'compiler_error'
- Puct -> '!'
- Group 
-- Delimiter::Parenthesis
-- TokenStream
---- Literal -> "my error"
```

That's how it works.

Everything else is just 'magic' to make it easier to use.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75506477/1311434) answer still gives the full macro call as the span for the error.
But the `syn` crate carefully sets the span of all produced tokens, so the error points to an exact spot *within* the macro call.

**So, this is the full example using the `compiler_error!` trick, without using `syn` or `quote!` that pinpoints the exact location of the error:**

```rust
fn my_macro_impl(input: TokenStream) -> Result<TokenStream, Span> {
    //parse input and generate output
    //...
    if oops {
        return Err(span_where_the_error_occurred);
    }
    //...
    Ok(output_stream)
}

#[proc_macro]
pub fn my_macro(input: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    use proc_macro::TokenTree as TT;
    match my_macro_impl(input) {
        Ok(output_stream) => output_stream,
        Err(span) => [
        TT::Punct({
            let mut punct = Punct::new(':', Spacing::Joint);
            punct.set_span(span);
            punct
        }),
        TT::Punct({
            let mut punct = Punct::new(':', Spacing::Alone);
            punct.set_span(span);
            punct
        }),
        TT::Ident(Ident::new("core", span)),
        TT::Punct({
            let mut punct = Punct::new(':', Spacing::Joint);
            punct.set_span(span);
            punct
        }),
        TT::Punct({
            let mut punct = Punct::new(':', Spacing::Alone);
            punct.set_span(span);
            punct
        }),
        TT::Ident(Ident::new("compile_error", span)),
        TT::Punct({
            let mut punct = Punct::new('!', Spacing::Alone);
            punct.set_span(span);
            punct
        }),
        TT::Group({
            let mut group = Group::new(Delimiter::Brace, {
                TokenStream::from_iter(vec![TT::Literal({
                    let mut string = Literal::string("Error: it wen wron HERE");
                    string.set_span(span);
                    string
                })])
            });
            group.set_span(span);
            group
        }),].into_iter().collect(),
            )),
        ]
        .into_iter()
        .collect(),
    }
}
```

Note how every `TokenTree` node has it's span set. Otherwise they would default to `Span::call_site()`.