# How to use declarative macro nested invocation other function-like procedural macro, can it works?

Tags: rust, rust-macros

I use a declarative macro nested invocation other procedural macro, from `arr![1_u32;2]` to `arr_proc([1_u32;2])`.
I don't want to call `arr_proc!` directly.
But I may got something wrong, when I compile the rust code.
It seems like the compiler can not expanded all the macro at some time.

My proc macro:

```rust
#[proc_macro]
pub fn arr_proc(input: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    let repeat_expr: ExprRepeat = parse(input)
        .expect("Like arr!([Test::default(); 16])");

    let mut len = 0;
    // get length from repeat_expr
    if let Expr::Lit(expr_lit) = repeat_expr.len.deref() {
        if let Lit::Int(int_lit) = &expr_lit.lit {
            len = int_lit.base10_parse::<usize>().expect("Failed to parse integer literal");
        }
    }
    // parse and concat
    let _expr = repeat_expr.expr;
    // 1. generate the arr
    let mut _all = quote!();
    for _i in 0..len {
        // 2. append element into arr
        _all = quote! { #_all #_expr, };
    }
    // 3. add []
    let arr = quote! { [ #_all ] };
    return arr.into();
}
```

My declarative macro:

```rust
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! arr {
    ($ele:expr; $repeat:literal) => {
        custom_proc_macro::arr_proc!([$ele; $repeat])
    };
}
```

My test case:

```rust
#[test]
fn test_arr_() {
    let a: [u32; 2] = arr![1_u32;2];
    dbg!(a);
}
```

The error is:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> tests/custom_proc_macro_test.rs:48:23
   |
48 |     let a: [u32; 2] = arr![1_u32;2];
   |            --------   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected an array with a fixed size of 2 elements, found one with 0 elements
   |            |     |
   |            |     help: consider specifying the actual array length: `0`
   |            expected due to this
   |
   = note: expected array `[u32; 2]`
              found array `[_; 0]`
   = note: this error originates in the macro `custom_proc_macro::arr_proc` which comes from the expansion of the macro `arr` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
The meaning probably the compiler expanded the declarative macro and did not expand the proc macro.
```

How can I use like this?
Can it works?

Comment: It's a code smell to use `Deref::deref` with method syntax, just use `*repeat_expr.len` instead.

Answer (score 0):

By using `if-let` without an `else` you're silencing all possible error conditions, the particular error here is that the declarative macro wraps the literals in undelimited [`Group`s](https://doc.rust-lang.org/proc_macro/struct.Group.html) and thus your `if let Expr::Lit(expr_lit) = ...` fails silently.
You can still parse it by replacing that whole `if-let` statement by something like this:

```rust
let lit_expr = match *repeat_expr.len {
    Expr::Group(group) => match *group.expr {
        Expr::Lit(lit) => lit,
        _ => panic!("expected literal"),
    },
    Expr::Lit(lit) => lit,
    _ => panic!("expected literal or group"),
};
let len = if let Lit::Int(int_lit) = lit_expr.lit {
    int_lit
        .base10_parse::<usize>()
        .expect("Failed to parse integer literal")
} else {
    panic!("expected integer literal");
};
```

I'm using `panic!` here for brevity and because [`Span::error`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/proc_macro/struct.Span.html#method.error) is not stable yet. You can read [How to report errors in a procedural macro using the quote macro?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54392702/how-to-report-errors-in-a-procedural-macro-using-the-quote-macro) to see how to produce better error messages. But you definitely shouldn't silently ignore the unexpected cases like you did.